SharedWorker close Memory leaks due to invalidity
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <button id="btn">click</button>
  </body>

  <script>
    const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

    function a1() {
      let shared = new SharedWorker("./1.js");

      if (shared !== null) {
        shared.port.close();
        shared = null;
      }
    }

    btn.onclick = () => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 20 * 1000; i++) {
        setTimeout(a1, 0);
      }
    };
  </script>
</html>


// 1.js
onconnect = (ev) => {
  ev.ports[0].close();
};


I shut it down, but it still doesn't free up memory.
I checked it with chrome memory and it showed no release, but I didn't have any references to it.
enter image description here
Normal memory release

Here is my trimmed down .htm file. I am able to reproduce the issue with just this short chunk of html/javascript:
